# Metal View (MTKView) Drawing Size Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, view, metal

Here I have a MTKView and running a simple CIFilter live on camera feed.  This works fine.

### Issue

On older devices' selfie camera's, such as iPhone 5, iPad Air, the feed gets drawn on a smaller area.  **UPDATE**: Found out that CMSampleBuffer fed to MTKView is smaller in size when this happens.  I guess the texture in each update needs to be scaled up?

---

```
 import UIKit
 import MetalPerformanceShaders
 import MetalKit
 import AVFoundation

    final class MetalObject: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {

        private var metalBufferView            : MTKView?
        private var metalDevice                = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        private var metalCommandQueue          : MTLCommandQueue!
        private var metalSourceTexture         : MTLTexture?
        private var context                    : CIContext?
        private var filter                     : CIFilter?


        init(with frame: CGRect, filterType: Int, scaledUp: Bool) {
            super.init()

            self.metalCommandQueue = self.metalDevice!.makeCommandQueue()
            self.metalBufferView = MTKView(frame: frame, device: self.metalDevice)
            self.metalBufferView!.framebufferOnly = false
            self.metalBufferView!.isPaused = true

            self.metalBufferView!.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.main.nativeScale
            self.metalBufferView!.delegate = self
            self.context = CIContext()


        }


        final func update (sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {

            var textureCache : CVMetalTextureCache?
            CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, self.metalDevice!,  nil, &textureCache)
            var cameraTexture: CVMetalTexture?

            guard
                let cameraTextureCache = textureCache,
                let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
                    return
            }

            let cameraTextureWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
            let cameraTextureHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
            CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                      cameraTextureCache,
                                                      pixelBuffer,
                                                      nil,
                                                      MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm,
                                                      cameraTextureWidth,
                                                      cameraTextureHeight,
                                                      0,
                                                      &cameraTexture)

            if let cameraTexture = cameraTexture,
                let metalTexture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(cameraTexture) {
                self.metalSourceTexture = metalTexture
                self.metalBufferView!.draw()
            }


        }

        //MARK: - Metal View Delegate
        final func draw(in view: MTKView) {

            guard let currentDrawable = self.metalBufferView!.currentDrawable,
                let sourceTexture = self.metalSourceTexture
                else {  return  }

            let commandBuffer = self.metalCommandQueue!.makeCommandBuffer()
            var inputImage = CIImage(mtlTexture: sourceTexture)!.applyingOrientation(self.orientationNumber)

            if self.showFilter {
                self.filter!.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                inputImage = filter!.outputImage!
            }


            self.context!.render(inputImage, to: currentDrawable.texture, commandBuffer: commandBuffer, bounds: inputImage.extent, colorSpace: self.colorSpace!)

            commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable)
            commandBuffer.commit()

        }


        final func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {

        }
    }
```

---

### Observations

- Only happens on selfie cameras of older devices
- Selfie cameras on newer devices are fine
  when the issue occurs, new content gets drawn in a smaller area (gravitated towards top left), with old content from back camera is still remaining outside of new content.
- Constraints and the sizing/placement of Metal View is fine.
- self.metalBufferView!.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.main.nativeScale
  solves the weird scaling issue on Plus devices.

Comment: Is it possible the front camera on the older devices is simply lower resolution?

Comment: @DevinLane precisely.!

Comment: Great, so then just draw it to whatever display bounds you want it to be at and it'll scale up. That's the `bounds` argument in the render call. Currently you're specifying the bounds of the input texture, but you want the bounds of the destination (screen size) texture.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on these on an answer below? I am new to Metal and confused on certain aspects.  Also, I can give the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the resolution of the front (selfie) camera on older devices is lower, so you'll need to scale the video up if you want it to use the full width or height. Since you're already using CIContext and Metal, you can simply instruct the rendering call to draw the image to whatever rectangle you like.

In your `draw` method, you execute

```
self.context!.render(inputImage,
                     to: currentDrawable.texture,
                     commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                     bounds: inputImage.extent,
                     colorSpace: self.colorSpace!)
```

The `bounds` argument is the *destination* rectangle in which the image will be rendered. Currently, you are using the image extent, which means the image will not be scaled.

To scale the video up, use the display rectangle instead. You can simply use your `metalBufferView.bounds` since this will be the size of your display view. You'll end up with

```
 self.context!.render(inputImage,
                      to: currentDrawable.texture,
                      commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                      bounds: self.metalBufferView.bounds,
                      colorSpace: self.colorSpace!)
```

If the image and the view are different aspect ratios (width/height is the aspect ratio), then you'll have to compute the correct size such that the image's aspect ratio is preserved. To do this, you'll end up with code like this:

```
CGRect dest = self.metalBufferView.bounds;
CGSize imageSize = inputImage.extent.size;
CGSize viewSize = dest.size; 
double imageAspect = imageSize.width / imageSize.height;
double viewAspect = viewSize.width / viewSize.height;
if (imageAspect > viewAspect) {
    // the image is wider than the view, adjust height
    dest.size.height = 1/imageAspect * dest.size.width;
} else {
    // the image is taller than the view, adjust the width
    dest.size.width = imageAspect * dest.size.height;

    // center the tall image
    dest.origin.x = (viewSize.width - dest.size.width) / 2;
}
```

Hope this is useful, please let me know if anything doesn't work or clarification would be helpful.

Comment: Changing to self.metalBufferView.bounds makes the view draw online ¼ of screen.  Even when I doubled the dimensions, it drew fine on normal cameras, but for those old selfie camera's it was still drawing smaller as before.

Comment: Hrm, well what are the dimensions indicated by the buffer view bounds, the input image, the current drawable's texture, and the specs for the selfie camera? All the info should be there to do the right scaling, unless one or more of those things is wrong... Perhaps the drawable's texture isn't the same size as the view?

Comment: Ah yeah I see, the currentDrawable's texture is the same size as the camera image. This needs to be the size of the view, so that when the camera image is drawn it will be scaled properly, and when the view draws the texture, it will be the size of the screen. Sorry I didn't notice that on the first pass!